# I can update my Sqlite database only once, how to get over this?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

As the title says: I can only update my SQLite database once. I use this code to generate the database and its tables:

```
    public static void GenDB()
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists("Key.sqlite"))
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("Key.sqlite");
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;

            m_dbConnection =
  new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Key.sqlite;Version=3;");
            m_dbConnection.Open();

            string createTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [MyKey] (
                      [ID] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                      [Key] VARCHAR(2048)  NULL
                      )";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(createTableQuery, m_dbConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            try
            {
                SQLiteConnection dbConnection;
                dbConnection =
                new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Key.sqlite;Version=3;");
                string sql = "insert into MyKey (Key) values ('yourkey')";
                SQLiteCommand commmand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, dbConnection);
                dbConnection.Open();
                commmand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Done");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error with adding to item to your Database ");
            }
        }
```

and this worked perfectly

The problem is in this code:

```
try
{
    string con = "Data Source=Key.sqlite;Version=3;";
    SQLiteConnection updata = new SQLiteConnection(con);

    updata.Open();

    string sql = "UPDATE MyKey SET Key=('" + Textbox + "') WHERE ID=1";

    SQLiteCommand commmand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, updata);
    commmand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error with updata to sql lite ");
}
```

It works the first time.. and when I try to build it again, I get error with update to `DB` the error message is `Database is locked`

Comment: when you say you get the error, im guessing you hitting `MessageBox.Show("Error with updata to sql lite ");` to see what the error is change `catch` to 'catch sqlException ex){ MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) Messagebox.Show(ex.StackTrace)}` this will tell you what your error is and if you can let us know what the error is then we can help you a little more

Comment: i Get `Database is locked` @SimonPrice

Comment: sorry for taking to long to get back to you, can you edit your question to give the full stacktrace and the error message please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre not closing your connection, which is why its getting locked, you should do your database work in a using statement which closes the connection when its finished.

```
using (SQLiteConnection sqlconn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
{
  sqlconn.Open();
  using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, c))
  {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

this is another way of using the using statement

```
 SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
                using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstringFromConfigFile"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn;
                    sqlconn.Open();
                    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    sqlcmd.CommandText = "sql statement";
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
```

Comment: should i close all connections i close it with this method but it did not work  @Simon Price

Comment: no, by using a using statement it will close it all off for you

Comment: the same **try
            {

                using (SQLiteConnection sqlconn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Key.sqlite;Version=3;"))
                {
                    sqlconn.Open();
                    string sql = "UPDATE MyKey SET Key=('" + Textbox + "') WHERE ID=1";

                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql,sqlconn))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                }
            catch(SQLiteException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }**

Comment: try the second method, in my edited answer, but i can confirm that that is working and live code, with the sqlconnection string genuine name ommited and the sql statement changed too.. but chanve sqlconnection to sqlliteconnection

Comment: the same Still `Locked`

Comment: have you got any tools that will allow you to interrogate the database other than going through your app. 

This suggests to me that the lock isnt coming from your app, unless youre opening a connection earlier in your application and not closing it.  Go through all the connections and see i you are or are not closing it. To close it once all the calls have been made `sqlconn.Close();`

Comment: Tools ? no i don't can recommend me one ? .. and close all connection and still get the same problem. `locked`

Comment: to be honest, no idea which is the bes tool, but take a look at this, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sqlite-database-browser-b/jlpbdkmaomigeneadlamehkfchdmojgg?hl=en it will be trial and error which works for you, but did you check your code for unclosed connections to the database?